# how verify username and password with feathersjs?

Tags: feathersjs

I want to authenticate by username and password.I use feathers authentication to do this but i don't understand after configuration my app , how verify my input data (username and password) in my server to allow feathers authenticate use it ?
In my client i have this code to send my data (username and password)

```
app.authenticate({
    strategy: 'local',
    username: 'k0',//self.state.username,
    password:'kk'// self.state.password
  }).then(response => {
    console.log('Authenticated!', response);
  return app.passport.verifyJWT(response.accessToken);
})
.then(payload => {
  console.log('JWT Payload', payload);
  return app.service('users').get(payload.userId);
})
.then(user => {
  app.set('user', user);
  console.log('User', app.get('user'));
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.error('Error authenticating!', error);
});
```

But i have an error

```
"POST http://localhost:4200/authentication 400 (Bad Request)
Error authenticating! 
BadRequest {type: "FeathersError", name: "BadRequest", message: "Missing credentials", code: 400, className: "bad-request", …}
className
:
"bad-request"
code
:
400
data
:
{message: "Missing credentials"}
errors
:
{}
message
:
"Missing credentials"
name
:
"BadRequest"
type
:
"FeathersError"
stack
:
"BadRequest: Missing credentials↵    at new BadRequest 
__proto__
:
Error"
```

And this my server.js

```
var Users=[ {_id:"1",email:"k0",password:"kk"}, {_id:"2",email:"k1",password:"kk"}, {_id:"3",email:"k2",password:"kk"}, {_id:"4",email:"k3",password:"kk"}, {_id:"5",email:"k4",password:"kk"}]; 
const feathers = require('feathers'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const errors = require('feathers-errors'); 
const errorHandler = require('feathers-errors/handler'); 
const rest = require('feathers-rest'); 
const hooks = require('feathers-hooks'); 
const auth = require('feathers-authentication'); 
const local = require('feathers-authentication-local'); 
const memory = require('feathers-memory'); 
const jwt = require('feathers-authentication-jwt');
 const app = feathers(); app.use(bodyParser.json()) app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); var cors = require('cors'); var port= process.env.PORT ||4200;app.use(cors());
`

.use('/users', {
find(params) {
return Promise.resolve(Users);
}
})
.use(errorHandler());
app.service('authentication').hooks({
before: {
create: [
auth.hooks.authenticate('local'),
customizeJWTPayload()
],
remove: [
auth.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
]
}
});
app.service('users').hooks({
before: {

create: [
  local.hooks.hashPassword({ passwordField: 'password' })
]
}
`});app.post('/login', auth.express.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/app', failureRedirect: '/login'     }));

app.get('/app', (req, res, next) => {
res.json({ success: true });
});

app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
res.json({ success: "faux" });
});
app.listen(port);`
```

Comment: The default username property is `email`. Did you change it to `username` in [your configuration](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#default-options)?

Comment: but if i do this
 app.authenticate({
    strategy: 'local',
    email: 'k0',//self.state.username,
    password:'kk'// self.state.password
  })
i have an other error "BadRequest: Missing credentials".

Answer (score 2):

**I strongly recommend that you use the feathers generator.** It works really well and will save you lots of time with these issues. That way you know that the basic services and authentication will work before you start customizing. https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/generators/readme.html

After discussing below with Developper below it seems the problem was using `username` instead of the default `email` for the authentication `usernameField` field. Either update the code to use `email` or create a default.json file with something like this:

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "strategies": [
      "local"
    ],
    "local": {
      "entity": "user",
      "usernameField": "username",
      "passwordField": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

Secondly, it's possible that your service is not set up correctly (which is why you are getting the `the id property must be set on the entity service for authentication` error.

Here is my users.service.js file:

```
// Initializes the `users` service on path `/users`
const createService = require('feathers-mongodb');
const hooks = require('./users.hooks');
const filters = require('./users.filters');

module.exports = function () {
  const app = this;
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');
  const mongoClient = app.get('mongoClient');
  const options = { paginate };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/users', createService(options));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('users');

  mongoClient.then(db => {
    service.Model = db.collection('users');
  });

  service.hooks(hooks);

  if (service.filter) {
    service.filter(filters);
  }
};
```

It looks like yours is set up to handle the query, but that is taken care of in the mongodb service using hooks: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongodb.html#querying

For the specific question of how feathers authentication verifies username and password Feathers authentication uses hooks. If you used `feathers generate service` and selected authentication then it automatically placed a call to the `authenticate()` in your service's hook file (typically `SERVICENAME.hooks.js`).

You can see what the `authenticate()` function is actually doing here: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/src/hooks/authenticate.js

Comment: Have you already created the user with the username and password that you are trying to authenticate?

I use curl: `curl 'http://localhost:3030/users/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{ "username": "k0", "password": "kk" }'`

Comment: Usually you would do this in the client. For testing your server you can run that curl command on the terminal. But ultimately you will want to have a user signup portion of your app. I'm not using feathers client myself but have a look at the guide here: https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/basic-feathers/rest-client.html

Comment: In this link not exists this curl method .

Comment: That's correct, the link discusses how to make a more robust client for your feathers server. The curl method is simply using the API to create a user. They are two separate ways to create a user. Did you try the curl command in your terminal?

Comment: So I must remove this method ? 
app.authenticate({
    strategy: 'local',
    username: 'k0',//self.state.username,
    password:'kk'// self.state.password
  })

Comment: Yes my users are created in array 
var Users=[
{_id:"1",username:"k0",password:"kk"}];

Comment: Can you post your default.config file here? Your problem may be what daff said above about your authentication config.

Comment: I haven't fil config , i have just server.js file and lgin.js file inside it i have my form login .

Comment: If you don't have a default.json config then the default authentication fields are `email` and `password`. Try changing `var Users=[ {_id:"1",username:"k0",password:"kk"}];` to `var Users=[ {_id:"1",email:"k0",password:"kk"}];` and also change `username` to `email` in  `app.authenticate`.

Comment: I did this but i have this error on click my submit button
`POST http://localhost:4200/authentication 500 (Internal Server Error)
proxyConsole.js:56 Error authenticating! GeneralError {type: "FeathersError", name: "GeneralError", message: "the `id` property must be set on the entity service for authentication", code: 500, className: "general-error", …} `

Comment: I don't see where you created your `users` service in this code, but there could be an issue with how you set the name of the `id` field. It should default to `_id` but maybe you are setting it to something else by accident. https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongodb.html#serviceoptions

Comment: I created my service here 
`app.use('/users', {
find(params) {
return Promise.resolve(Users);
}
})`
It is false ?

Comment: I don't think that is correct for the service setup. I edited my answer above and my entire `users.service.js` file. It looks like your service is only set up to handle the query, but that is taken care of in the mongodb service using hooks: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongodb.html#querying

Comment: Any luck @Developper?

Comment: It seems that i have many problems because i am beginner with feathersjs. I must repeat all my code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Developper: I strongly recommend that you use the feathers generator. It works really well and will save you lots of time with these issues. That way you know that the basic services and authentication will work before you start customizing. https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/generators/readme.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice , i will try it

Comment: If this helped you consider accepting the answer so other people can easily find this later. Good luck!